# Database not updated with no exception message

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I cannot find the reason why my database table is not updated. Below is my code.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
            sqlConnection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Transitionday.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            sqlConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Transitionday SET Busnumber ='" + label1.Text + "', DT1check1 = '" + dataGridView1[1, 0].Value + "' where Id = '" + textBox4.Text + "'", sqlConnection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        this.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `WHERE` clause in a `SELECT` statement directly against the database and checking it returns the results you're expecting it to? Also your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You dont get any error in Catch block.? What is the `DataType` defined for `DT1check1` in DB .?

Comment: @Diado Hmm, `where` and `select` means like `"SELECT Busnumber from Transitionday WHERE Busnumber ='" + label1.Text + "'";` then displaying the data? Trivial qtn but I am new to this.

Comment: @SH7. Nope. My `DataType` is `bool`. `DT1check1` is a checkbox column.

Comment: "SELECT * from Transitionday  where Id = '" + textBox4.Text + "'"

Comment: Having the quotes around the ID should still work fine if that column is a numeric datatype.  If the update truly isn't happening, then I suspect that the real problem may be that the ID being fed into the SQL statement doesn't exist in the database table.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Id column type in the database? Because your script is assuming its value needs to be wrapped in quotes.

```
"' where Id = '" + textBox4.Text + "'"
```

translates to

```
where Id = 'whatItyped'
```

If your Id column is a string (varchar, nvarchar) or a guid, then that is correct. If your Id column is an int, it is not correct.

If it is not correct, then `where Id = 'whatItyped'` is going to return 0 hits, which means that 0 rows will be updated. And that's not an error, so the database or the code does not actually give you an error response.

You would need your script to be

```
where Id = 123
```

which means your code needs to be changed to

```
"' where Id = " + textBox4.Text
```

Notice that the `'` characters were removed.